# How do I give a user an option to use my app as default with android

Tags: java, android, default

I am making an app that is filtering videos through ID when a link is clicked through deep links. It works but the user has to set the app to open as default. How do I make the little window asking if they would always want to open YouTube links with my app within an activity?

Comment: Last I checked, there is no option for this.